# Type-safe npm library for handling normalized data stored in Redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, redux, relationship

I'm looking for a library to denormalize data structure with one-to-many, many-to-one, many-to-many and one-to-one relationships in Redux store.

Example:

```
{
  "users": {
    "a": { "id": "a", "name": "A" },
    "b": { "id": "b", "name": "B" }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "posts": {
    "x": { "id": "x", "authorId": "a" },
    "y": { "id": "y", "authorId": "b" },
    "z": { "id": "z", "authorId": "c" }
  }
}
```

should be converted into something like:

```
{
  "posts": {
    "x": { "id": "x", "authorId": "a", "author": { "id": "a", "name": "A" } },
    "y": { "id": "y", "authorId": "b", "author": { "id": "b", "name": "B" } },
    "z": { "id": "z", "authorId": "a", "author": { "id": "a", "name": "A" } },
  }
}
```

Produced data does not have to be exactly the same as the example, but at least should be strictly typed.

Currently I always use `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(***).map(([key, value]) => ***)` in selectors, which is hard to read.

Comment: Have you looked into `normalizr`?  https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr  I don't use it so I don't know how strongly typed it is.  Usually I just define the schemas myself.  If the redux store itself is strongly typed, you shouldn't need to get too tricky in your selectors.  It's probably easier if `relationships` are a separate property rather than having `authorId` as a top-level property, but you can still do it.  I can answer with some sample code later.

Comment: `normalizr` seems to do exactly what I want to do, and has built-in TypeScript definition.
However, the definition for `denormalize` method says it returns `any`.

Comment: Redux selectors will be complex if the container components have deeply nested presentational components. Also, I have TypeScript's `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` option turned on, so I always have to check if the relation is valid.